# Access value on window from Google Tag Manager custom html tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have some javascript I am using a GTM custom html tag to inject on my page. I need to access a value that is on the window, is there a way to do this from GTM or do I need to put the script in my actual html now to get this value for my script?

Here is an example of what I have now that is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(window.awesomeValue);
</script>
```

When I inspect the source after GTM injects the script the `window.awesomeValue` appears literally and is not being evaluated.

Thanks!

Comment: In the script that is injected on the page you will see exactly what you have written in the HTML tag (not evaluated), the value will be only evaluated in the console. If you don't see the value in the console output but it literally says "window.awesomeValue" then can you please post browser you are using? (I didn't encountered this problem in Chrome)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a JavaScript variable to hold the value. Try this:

1. Create a `JavaScript Variable` and set the value to `window.awesomeValue`
2. Modify your custom HTML tag to use the newly created variable:

Your final code will look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log({{yourNewJSVariable}});
</script>
```